# Where does nm-tool get its output?

Tags: dns

I am using Linux Mint and the output from the `nm-tool` is:

```
DNS: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 
DNS: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Where does `nm-tool` get these DNS IPs?

From which file in the OS's file system?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us what operating system you are using. If Linux, also tell us which distribution. I was under the impression that `nm-tool` isn't in active use anymore and has mostly been replaced by `nmcli`.

Answer (score 1):

As @terdon commented, `nm-tool` seems to be an obsolete utility.

`nm-tool` communicates with `NetworkManager` which can get DNS IPs from many possible sources:

- from the DHCP responses, if any network interface has been configured to use DHCP (the DHCP response data for each NIC may be available as a file in `/var/lib/NetworkManager/` directory)
- from files in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` if any have been configured (NetworkManager's "native" configuration storage backend)
- from the file `/etc/network/interfaces` (NetworkManager's Debian/Ubuntu read-only backward-compatibilty configuration storage backend)
- from any NetworkManager VPN connection plug-ins, if any VPN connections are in use (VPNs may suggest their own DNS servers, analogously to DHCP but possibly using a different protocol for providing the information)
- from any per-user network configuration settings (e.g. on a laptop with per-user WiFi configurations), stored using whichever configuration storage backend is provided by the user's desktop environment of choice. For example, `dconf` for modern GNOME 3 uses `~/.config/dconf/user`.

`NetworkManager` may then write the current set of DNS server addresses to:

- directly into `/etc/resolv.conf` if the `resolvconf` package is not installed
- into `/etc/resolvconf/run/interface/NetworkManager` if `resolvconf` is installed (enabling the co-existence of both NetworkManager-aware and -unaware VPN solutions, as long as both will use `resolvconf` instead of directly modifying `/etc/resolv.conf`)
- or it might directly configure `systemd-resolved` if it's in use.

If `resolvconf` is in use, it will update `/etc/resolv.conf`, and/or the configuration of `system-resolved` if the latter is being used. It will also run any scripts in `/etc/resolvconf/update.d` and `/etc/resolvconf/update-libc.d` to notify any processes that have an interest in knowing when system-wide DNS resolver settings are being changed and have provided a notifier script.

If IPv6 is being used and `rdnssd` daemon has been installed, it is also possible to receive IPv6 DNS server information attached to IPv6 router advertisement packets, if the IPv6 router administrator has chosen to offer that information. Depending on distribution, `rdnssd` might default to using `resolvconf` or modifying `/etc/resolv.conf` directly.

And if you have a recent enough version of Mint, it might be using [Netplan](https://netplan.io) like modern Ubuntu does, which adds one more possible source for all network configuration settings, including DNS settings: `/etc/netplan/*.yaml` files.

So... yes, it's rather complicated!